# How to use condition checking inside LINQ select new{ }

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory

I want to assign all my User properties from active directory into a List< User > properties by using LINQ.

For that I have tried some code but I am not able to assign `Manager` attribute on `List` User Manager property.

Because , assign the Manager attribute value from Active directory we need to search the manager user on active directory and based on the search result we need to assign manager attribute value to  List of User.Manager property.

Here is my Code,

```
public List< User > GetADUsers()
{
  DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ADEntry);
  searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)objectCategory=person)";      
  SearchResultCollection resultCol = searcher.FindAll();

  return 
    (from serachresult in resultCol.OfType<SearchResult>()
     let result = serachresult.GetDirectoryEntry()                       
     result.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value != null
     select new User
     {
       GivenName = result.Properties.Contains("givenname") ?
         Convert.ToString(result.Properties["givenname"][0]) : "",
       SurName = result.Properties.Contains("sn") ?   
         Convert.ToString(result.Properties["sn"][0]) : "",
       Location = result.Properties.Contains("physicalDeliveryOfficeName") ? 
         Convert.ToString(result.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0]) : "",     
       Manager= ?// Here I need to assign the manager attribute from active directory
     }
    ).ToList();
}
```

By using below mentioned code, I am taking the manager attribute from `Active Directory` by using `directory entry` object. I want to place this code on above mentioned LINQ query 
on Manager property. How can we achieve this inside of LINQ Select clause.

```
DirectoryEntry DomainRoot = AD.GetDirectoryEntry();
using (DirectorySearcher Search = new DirectorySearcher())
{
   Search.SearchRoot = DomainRoot;
   Search.Filter = "(&(distinguishedName=" + 
     Convert.ToString(result.Properties["manager"][0]) + "))";
   SearchResult Result = Search.FindOne();
   if (Result != null)
   {
     DirectoryEntry Manager = Result.GetDirectoryEntry();
     //This Manager.Name value I have assign above mentioned LINQ
     user.Manager = Manager.Name.Substring(3);    
     Manager.Close();
   }
}
```

Please help me to assign the manager name on the LINQ query Manager property place! Thanks.

Comment: *Please* make more of an effort to format your code before posting. Note how there's a huge amount of space to the left of your code... and we need to scroll to the right to actually see it all.

Comment: (I tried formatting your code myself, but the part in the middle of the return statement makes no sense...) As well as paying attention to the formatting, you should reduce your problem to a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem. It's hard to see the wood for the trees here.

Comment: Too much mess to read and understand, Please reformat your code and edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your manager evaluation to a new function that takes 'result' and returns Manager name.
And then call it from your link statement: Manager = GetManagerName(result)

```
    public string GetManagerName(DirectoryEntry dirEntry)
    {
        DirectoryEntry DomainRoot = AD.GetDirectoryEntry();
        using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher())
        {
            search.SearchRoot = DomainRoot;
            search.Filter = "(&(distinguishedName=" + Convert.ToString(dirEntry.Properties["manager"][0]) + "))";
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry mgr = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    return mgr.Name.Substring(3);
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent. Its working now with out any error. This is what I need. Thank you so much.